# Lista de objetos no se vincula al modelo en .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, formularios, asp.net-core

Tengo un formulario en mi aplicación .Net Core 2.2 que no llega correctamente al controlador.

El objeto siempre llega vacío al controlador.

He probado de todo y ya no se qué mas hacer. De hecho tenía todo con View Components, pero los he reducido para poder pasarle a los "name" el indice y que se puedan formar las listas.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias!

Este es el DataSet (He probado vía Ajax y tampoco funciona)

> ListFieldEditorViewModel[0].Items[0].Id: 95
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[0].Items[0]Type: Text
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[0].Items[0].Name: DNI Titular
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[0].Items[0].Description: DNI Titular
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[0].Items[0].OriginalValue: DNI Titular
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[0].Items[0].CorrectedValue:
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[0].Items[1].Id: 96
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[0].Items[1]Type: Text
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[0].Items[1].Name: Nombre Titular
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[0].Items[1].Description: Nombre Titular
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[0].Items[1].OriginalValue: Nombre Titular
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[0].Items[1].CorrectedValue:
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[1].Items[0].Id: 97
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[1].Items[0]Type: Text
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[1].Items[0].Name: DNI Avalista
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[1].Items[0].Description: DNI Avalista
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[1].Items[0].OriginalValue: DNI Avalista
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[1].Items[0].CorrectedValue:
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[1].Items[1].Id: 98
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[1].Items[1]Type: Text
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[1].Items[1].Name: Nombre Avalista
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[1].Items[1].Description: Nombre Avalista
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[1].Items[1].OriginalValue: Nombre Avalista
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[1].Items[1].CorrectedValue:
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[2].Items[0].Id: 99
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[2].Items[0]Type: Text
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[2].Items[0].Name: DNI Hipotecante
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[2].Items[0].Description: DNI Hipotecante
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[2].Items[0].OriginalValue: DNI Hipotecante
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[2].Items[0].CorrectedValue:
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[2].Items[1].Id: 100
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[2].Items[1]Type: Text
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[2].Items[1].Name: Nombre Hipotecante
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[2].Items[1].Description: Nombre Hipotecante
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[2].Items[1].OriginalValue: Nombre Hipotecante
>   ListFieldEditorViewModel[2].Items[1].CorrectedValue:

El método del controlador (Está inacabado, por eso solo devuelve la vista, pero es suficiente para comprobar si llega el objeto correctamente)

```
public IActionResult GuardarDatos(List<ListFieldEditorViewModel> formulario)
    {
        return View(formulario);
    }
```

El formulario

```
model List<IntervinienteViewModel>
        <form id="formIntervinientes" method="post" asp-antiforgery="false" asp-action="GuardarDatos" asp-controller="Expediente">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnGuardar"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#titulares" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="headingTitulares" id="headingTitulares">
                <span class="text-primary mb-0">Titulares</span>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="titulares" aria-labelledby="headingTitulares">
                <div class="card-body">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < titulares.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="card mb-2">
                            <div class="card-body bg-light">
                                <vc:interviniente dato="titulares[i]" index="@count" subseccion="IntervinienteTitular"></vc:interviniente>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        count++;
                    }                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#avalistas" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="headingAvalistas" id="headingAvalistas">
                <span class="text-primary mb-0">Avalistas</span>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="avalistas" aria-labelledby="headingAvalistas">
                <div class="card-body">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < avalistas.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="card mb-2">
                            <div class="card-body bg-light">
                                <vc:interviniente dato="avalistas[i]" index="@count" subseccion="IntervinienteAvalista"></vc:interviniente>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        count++;
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card mb-4">
            <div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hipotecantes" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="headingHipotecantes" id="headingHipotecantes">
                <span class="text-primary mb-0">Hipotecantes</span>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="hipotecantes" aria-labelledby="headingHipotecantes">
                <div class="card-body">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < hipotecantes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="card mb-2">
                            <div class="card-body bg-light">
                                <vc:interviniente dato="hipotecantes[i]" index="@count" subseccion="IntervinienteHipotecante"></vc:interviniente>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        count++;
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

El View Component Interviniente

```
model ListFieldEditorViewModel
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
    <label class="font-weight-bold">
        <span class="fas fa-info-circle text-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@Model.Description"></span>
        @Model.Description
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <input asp-for="Id" id="hdId_@uniqueId" type="hidden" readonly />
        <input asp-for="Type" id="hdType_@uniqueId" type="hidden" readonly />
        <input asp-for="Name" id="hdName_@uniqueId" type="hidden" readonly />
        <input asp-for="Description" id="hdDescription_@uniqueId" type="hidden" readonly />

        @if (Model.Type == EnumTipoCampo.Text)
        {
            <input asp-for="OriginalValue" id="txtOriginalValue_@uniqueId" type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" readonly />
        }
        else if (Model.Type == EnumTipoCampo.Date)
        {

            DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact(Model.OriginalValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            <input asp-for="OriginalValue" id="txtOriginalValue_@uniqueId" type="text" class="datepicker form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" readonly value="@value.ToShortDateString()" />
        }
        else if (Model.Type == EnumTipoCampo.Decimal)
        {
            decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(Model.OriginalValue);
            <input asp-for="OriginalValue" id="txtOriginalValue_@uniqueId" type="text" class=" form-control decimal mb-2 mr-sm-2" readonly value="@value.ToString("n2")" />
        }
        else if (Model.Type == EnumTipoCampo.Integer)
        {
            decimal value = Convert.ToInt32(Model.OriginalValue);
            <input asp-for="OriginalValue" id="txtOriginalValue_@uniqueId" type="number" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" readonly value="@value.ToString()" />
        }
        else if (Model.Type == EnumTipoCampo.Boolean)
        {
            <select asp-for="OriginalValue" id="txtOriginalValue_@uniqueId" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" disabled>
                <option value="Y">Sí</option>
                <option value="N">No</option>
            </select>
        }

        @{
            string chk1 = "", chk2 = "", chk3 = "";
            string display = "none";

            if (Model.Status.HasValue)
            {
                if (Model.Status.Value == 1)
                {
                    chk1 = "checked";
                    display = "none";
                }
                else if (Model.Status.Value == 2)
                {
                    chk2 = "checked";
                    display = "block";
                }
                else if (Model.Status.Value == 3)
                {
                    chk3 = "checked";
                    display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-2 mr-sm-2">
            <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="chkOk_@uniqueId" name="Status_@uniqueId" value="1" @chk1>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkOk_@uniqueId">Correcto</label>
        </div>

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-2 mr-sm-2">
            <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="chkKO_@uniqueId" name="Status_@uniqueId" value="2" @chk2>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkKO_@uniqueId">Incorrecto</label>
        </div>

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-2 mr-sm-2">
            <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="chkND_@uniqueId" name="Status_@uniqueId" value="3" @chk3>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkND_@uniqueId">N/D</label>
        </div>


        @if (Model.Type == EnumTipoCampo.Text)
        {
            <input asp-for="CorrectedValue" id="CorrectedValue_@uniqueId" type="text" class="valorCorregido form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" style="display:@display" />
        }
        else if (Model.Type == EnumTipoCampo.Date)
        {
            <input asp-for="CorrectedValue" id="CorrectedValue_@uniqueId" type="text" class="valorCorregido form-control datepicker mb-2 mr-sm-2" style="display:@display" />
        }

        else if (Model.Type == EnumTipoCampo.Decimal)
        {
            <input asp-for="CorrectedValue" id="CorrectedValue_@uniqueId" type="text" class="valorCorregido form-control decimal mb-2 mr-sm-2" style="display:@display" />
        }
        else if (Model.Type == EnumTipoCampo.Integer)
        {
            <input asp-for="CorrectedValue" id="CorrectedValue_@uniqueId" type="number" class="valorCorregido form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" style="display:@display" />
        }
        else if (Model.Type == EnumTipoCampo.Boolean)
        {
            <select asp-for="CorrectedValue" id="CorrectedValue_@uniqueId" class="valorCorregido form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" style="display:@display">
                <option value="Y">Sí</option>
                <option value="N">No</option>
            </select>
        }
    </div>
    <hr style="border-color:#ddd" />
</div>
```

Y el modelo

```
public class ListFieldEditorViewModel
{
    public List<FieldEditorViewModel> Items { get; set; }
    public ListFieldEditorViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<FieldEditorViewModel>();
    }
}

public class FieldEditorViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public EnumTipoCampo Type { get; set; }

    public bool Mandatory { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }

    public string Table { get; set; }

    public string OriginalValue { get; set; }

    public string CorrectedValue { get; set; }

    public int? Status { get; set; }

    public int SubseccionId { get; set; }

    public int? Index { get; set; }

    public FieldEditorViewModel(Campo campo)
    {
        this.Name = campo.Nombre;
        this.Id = campo.Id;
        this.Type = (EnumTipoCampo)campo.TipoCampoId;
        this.Description = campo.Descripcion;
        this.Order = campo.Orden;
        this.Mandatory = campo.EsObligatorio;
        this.SubseccionId = campo.SubseccionId;

        if (Type == EnumTipoCampo.Date)
            this.OriginalValue = "01/01/1990";
        else if(Type==EnumTipoCampo.Integer || Type == EnumTipoCampo.Decimal)
            this.OriginalValue = "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, en tu formulario y en el ViewComponent, cómo tienes definida la directiva `@model` ?

Comment: En la vista del form model List<IntervinienteViewModel>

Al ViewComponent se le pasa un intervinienteViewModel, pero lo que devuelve es un ListFieldEditorViewModel, que es lo que tengo en la directiva: model ListFieldEditorViewModel

Comment: Pues edita la pregunta e indica todo eso en el código, así se verá mas claro. La información de los `@model`es fundamental para ver que está pasando.